# Database initialisation before bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am creating a timer application that uses Quartz, also am using spring to initialise my DB from schema.sql file. When application starts I want to DB be initialised before my Scheduler bean is created.

```
@Bean
public Scheduler scheduler() throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler scheduler;
    final StdSchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory("application.properties");
    stdSchedulerFactory.initialize();
    scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    return scheduler;
}
```

Scheduler bean is inside TimerConfiguration.java which is added to TimerApplication like

> @SpringBootApplication
>  @Import({TimerConfiguration.class})
>    public class TimerApplication {

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: I think `@PostConstruct` nor `@DependsOn` could help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@DependsOn` annotation specifies a bean which should be initialized after another bean got initialized.

It's recommended to set the name of the waiting bean as value in the annotation.

In your case its `@DependsOn("datasource")`.

More infos from the docs:

> Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are
> guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. Used
> infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on
> another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather
> depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization.
>
> May be used on any class directly or indirectly annotated with Component or
> on methods annotated with Bean.