# Execute h2-scripts before bean initialisation Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, h2, spring-bean

this is kind of a duplicate question ([Database initialisation before bean creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904104/database-initialisation-before-bean-creation)) but the given answer is somehow not working for me.

For testing purposes I am using a h2-db and therefore
I am also looking for a way that (h2)-database scripts are being executed before bean-initialisation, so I have the data ready for integration-tests

In theory the DependsOn behaviour is what I am looking for but for some reason its not working.

Under src/test/resources i have two sql scripts (data.sql and import.sql script)

application.yaml looks the following:

```
spring:
 config:
  activate:
   on-profile: test
 datasource:
  driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  url: jdbc:h2:mem:undgesund;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
 jpa:
  hibernate:
   ddl-auto: none
   naming:
     physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
 generate-ddl: false
 sql:
 init:
   mode: always
```

I have a bean declared in a @Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass { 

 @Bean
 @DependsOn("dataSource")
 public Map<Integer, SomeEntity> entityMap() {
    log.info("loading values into memory...");
    final List<SomeEntity> someEntities = this.dao.getAllEntities();
    for(SomeEntity someEntity: someEntities) {
        this.someEntityMap.put(someEntity.id(), someEntity);
  }
 }
}
```

DaoClass is basic and looks like that:

```
@Service
public class Dao {

  @Autowired
  private SomeEntityRepository someEntityRepository //basic JpaRepository
  public List<SomeEntity> getAllEntities {
    return entityRepository.findAll();
}
```

And I have an test-class

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest()
@Import({ConfigClass.class})
class SomeTestClass {

  @Autowired
  private SomeEntityRepository someEntityRepository

  @Test
  public void repoTest() {
    assertTrue(someEntityRepository.findAll() > 0)
  }
```

What happens now is, that when I am executing the test and the **@Bean entityMap** gets initialised, the repo is returning no data.
But when the test gets executed the repo returns some data and the tests succeeds.

How is it possible that the sql-scripts are getting executed so that data is in the h2-db and when **@Bean entityMap** is being created, data is actually getting returned?

Comment: Initialization of the datasource (execution the `schema.sql` and `data.sql`) happens after the `DataSource` is created, else there is no way to execute those scripts. When the `entityMap` is created there is no guaranty that those scripts have run.

Comment: so it means that its not possible to have the data ready when the Beans are getting created?

Comment: I didn't say that, I said there is no guaranty that it is executed. If you want to build a cache you should use a listener which executes after the context has fully started.

Comment: so I tried to do something like `@EventListener(classes = {{Various SpringContextEvents}}@Bean public Map<Integer, SomeEntity> entityMap()`
Unfortunately did not work.... 
Weird that this is so hard to accomplish

Comment: That will, imho obviously, not work. You cannot put an `@EventListener` on an `@Bean` method (well you could but it will not work as intended). You need to place this on a regular method that will fill the cache. Not on a methdo that returns the cache as a bean.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tried that but you can try to use [H2's INIT feature](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=init&search=init#execute_sql_on_connection)

so you could have something like this (I'm not sure if it reads from java classpath or not):

```yaml
spring:
 datasource:
  driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  url: jdbc:h2:mem:undgesund;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=runscript from 'schema.sql';runscript from 'data.sql'
```

**EDIT:**
seems like if you prefix the files with `classpath:` it should work.

```
url: jdbc:h2:mem:undgesund;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:schema.sql';runscript from 'classpath:data.sql'
```